# Custom CakePHP route with Regex

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.3.8 and I have this custom route.

```
Router::connect('/:regione/*', array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'region'), array('regione' => 'WHAT HERE??' ));
```

Now, I have to execute this route if my **:regione** ***IS NOT*** starting with the string **auth**.

Example:

```
example.com/abruzzo   (ok)
example.com/abruzzo/2 (ok)
example.com/abruzzo/3 (ok)
example.com/auth (NO)
example.com/auth/something (NO)
```

I do not know how to write this regex in this case, because I need to execute the route IF **DOES NOT MATCH/START** with **auth** string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a negative lookahead should do it:

```
(?!auth).*
```

This should match everything that doesn't start with `auth`, which means not even `authenticate` would match.

The internally compiled route regex will look like this:

```
#^(?:/(?P<regione>(?!auth).*))(?:/(?P<_args_>.*))?[/]*$#
```